# Error when building to device - error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, bundle, identifier

I'm using Parse.com as my database, and I started with a template provided by the instructor of an online Udemy course (file is attached in this link):

http://www.robpercival.co.uk/parse-working-on-xcode-7swift-2/

When I build on iOS simulator, it works fine. However, I'd like to run a build on my device, but I've had some problems.

Initially, when trying to run the build on my device, an X-Code pop-up came up with the following message and an option to 'Fix Issue' -

"No provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the bundle identifier “com.parse.appdem” were found.

Xcode attempt to fix this issue. This will reset your code signing and provisioning settings to recommended values and resolve issues with signing identities and provisioning profiles."

When I click on "Fix Issue", I got the following -

"An App ID with Identifier 'com.parse.appdem' is not available. Please enter a different string."

At that point, my bundle identifier was 'com.parse.appdem', which was originally in the template. Someone told me that deleting '.parse' worked for him. I tried that, but now, in the ReadList.xcodeproj file, I'm getting the following error:

error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any idea on how to resolve this provisioning issue?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be an answer but, are you registered as an Apple developer? Because you can only test your apps on a device if you are registered as an Apple developer.

In other words, you gotta pay the $100 to test on devices.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I have a free Apple developer account ... Which I thought allowed me to run builds on my device.  If not, ill register for a paid developer account immediately.

Comment: Yeah, you can register for free as an Apple Developer, but in order to test on devices and publish to the App Store you need to pay the $100 yearly fee. 

If this help don't forget to accept it as "answer" (:

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!  Much appreciated.

Comment: Yeah... Im just a beginner...but i'm really getting into it.  The learning curve was tough at first... But stack overflow and individuals like yourself have been a great support!

Comment: Swift is interesting in my opinion. I am learning it as well. The last time I worked on an app was last year, when they were still using Objective-C, but since then swift has been introduced, so in this summer break, I decided to get familiar with swift and more comfortable with Xcode. 
I would recommend a YouTube channel that has helped me a lot through my programming exercises. It's called "thenewboston" he has not only swift, but a whole lot other programming languages if it interests you.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you!  Ill check it out.  Quick question... Im using parse as my database. What is your opinion on parse?  Or Do you recommend that i learn SQL and Python for my server side database and scripting?

Comment: I'm actually building an application with Parse! So yeah I would recommend it. It's easy to use, and there are a lot of YouTube videos explaining how to use it, and people have done tutorials with Xcode and Swift with Parse. You just need to know basic SQL commands, but they are already included in Parse, so I would say go for it. Make your life easier and use Parse (:

Comment: By the way, did you pay for the course in Udemy? or you are doing the free preview?

Comment: Cool, thanks!  I actually caught a Udemy promotion and paid $10 for it.  I get the promo emails every now and then.  If you'd like ... I can forward it to you the next time I get one.

Comment: Team treehouse is awesome as well ... I've been finding it helpful to switch back and forth between YouTube, Udemy, and Team Treehouse.